# make view controller scrollable with collection view

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I need to create a view controller like this or like user instagram's  profile

[image]

not exactly same, I just want to add label and buttons and collection view,
but I want all of this in scroll viewController
I think I can't do that from storyboard, so how I can make a view controller scrollable programmatically?
and then I want to add the label and buttons inside the scroll , I can do that programmatically , but how I can add collection programmatically inside it?

Comment: Why are use programmatically ? I suggest story board for easy of adding and arranging objects..

Comment: @MohanSingh how I can do that in story board? I need the viewcontroller scrolling when I have a long text in the label

Comment: sorry i not able to understand what you exactly need. i said depend on that image, Use scroll view . if you need change height of the `view` on story Bord follow this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301896/how-to-use-storyboard-to-lay-out-screen-content-that-is-taller-than-the-screen-o

Comment: @MohanSingh thank you that is exactly what I need!! but the point I want to add some label in this scrollView, the contents and height of the label depend on what the user entered in it , so the height of contentView not fixed, its should depend on label height and other objects in the viewcontroller, how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions is to make the whole container a "UICollectionView" -or "UITableView", depends on what exactly you want to build-, and then, create a custom cell for each area depending on what do you want to display in it.

It might sounds a little bit strange in the beginning, but you will notice that it is a great technique to handle scrolling in your scene, including some of extra nice features, such as:

- auto scroll content resizing for "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" and "UIKeyboardWillHideNotification" events.
- the ease of showing and hiding sections from the UI (actually they are cells!).

**UPDATED**: For example:

[image]

You can make the first part (red rectangle) as a `UICollectionReusableView` and customize it by adding your images and button in it, second part (blue square) as a `UICollectionViewCell` and so on...

This is the general idea of what how you can do it.

Comment: I really I can't understand what you say, could you make it?